# Extjs create dynamic accordion using store

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, extjs4, accordion, store

I'm beginning development of an app in extjs. I'm using the MVC approach, as provided in the [extjs documentation](http://www.sencha.com/learn/the-mvc-application-architecture/).

I have some dynamic data which needs to present the user with a set of accordion controls. I've got the data in a store, but I do not know how to dynamically create the accordion items (unlike grid panels, there doesn't appear to be a store data method).

Here is my current accordion view code - with static items:

```
Ext.define('BP.view.induction.LeftPage', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
alias : 'widget.leftpage',

title: "Left Page", 
layout: {
    type: 'accordion',
    align: 'stretch'
},
layoutConfig: {
    // layout-specific configs go here
    titleCollapse: true,
    animate: true,
    activeOnTop: true
},
items: [{
    xtype: 'panel', // fake hidden panel, so all appear collapsed
    hidden: true,
    collapsed: false
},{
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: 'Panel 1',
    html: 'Panel content!'
},{
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: 'Panel 2',
    html: 'Panel content!'
},{
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: 'Panel 3',
    html: 'Panel content!'
}]
});
```

Any guidance on how to achieve the above would be appreciated, thank you.

[Edit] In response to sra's request, here is my controller:

```
Ext.define('BP.controller.Induction', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

views: [
    'induction.Binder'
],

stores: [
    'Sections',
    'Categories',
    'Tasks'
],

init: function() {
    console.log('Initialized Induction!');
}
});
```

I should note here that this controller loads a parent view, which in turn loads the LeftPage view - I'm not sure if this creates any scoping issues. Furthermore, as you can see, more than one store is loaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do like this (untested example with some tweaks)

```
Ext.define('BP.view.induction.LeftPage', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.leftpage',

    title: "Left Page", 
    layout: null,
    layoutConfig: null,
    store: null,
    attentive: true,
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;
        // begin edit
        // only set the store if is is not already defined
        me.store = me.store ? me.store : Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('Sections');  // you may change this to any storename you want
        // end edit
        me.layout = { // don't set objects directly in class definitions
            type: 'accordion',
            align: 'stretch'
        };
        me.layoutConfig = { // dont set objects directly in class definitions
            titleCollapse: true,
            animate: true,
            activeOnTop: true
        };

        me.callParent(arguments);
        if (me.attentive) {
            me.store('load', me.onRebuildContent, me);
            if (me.store.count() == 0)
                me.store.load();
        } else {
            me.buildContent(); 
        }
    },
    buildContent: function() {
        var me = this;
        function addItem(rec) {
            me.add({
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: rec.get('titleProperty'),
                html: rec.get('bodyProprty')
            });
        };

        me.store.each(addItem);
    },
    onRebuildContent: function() {
        var me = this;
        me.removeAll();
        me.buildContent();
    }   
});
```

Your store will need at least two properties; one for the title and one for the content. And the store need to be loaded before you should instantiate this. But that can easily be done within your controller.

**Edit based on comment and new OP info:**

Well your view is a bit out of control of the controller. So I recommend you to simply use the **[StoreManager](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.StoreManager)** to receive a valid instance (I've edited the code, I just didn'T know the correct store to use). The StoreManager will know about the store as long as you list him within a controller (StoreManager is capable of much more, but that is all you need to know at the moment). For a further release you could also use the mixin **[bindable](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.util.Bindable)** which would manage a storebinding more clean and enables you to update your accordion after the store receives new data (get updated)

**Edit for readability**

I've just cleaned it up a bit and included a switch param `attentive` which would allow you to use this component as directly bound to a store, reacting on all load events or as a sort of static one where the store should already be loaded. All in all this should give you a start without making it to complex.

Comment: Thanks for the help sra. I've added the code and changed this line: `me.sections.each(addItem);` and I'm loading the store using 'stores' parameter in the controller, but it's telling me that it is undefined. I'm sure this is something quite obvious, but as I'm a extjs newbie I'm still struggling with the basics. Any assistance you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @BrynJ Well, I guess it is straight forward from there on; create instance of `'BP.view.induction.LeftPage'` using `Ext.create('BP.view.induction.LeftPage', { store: yourStoreVariable });` instead of `Ext.widget()`. If this not help please drop the controller function where you instantiate this class and I will see what I can do.

Comment: I'm sure it is obvious, but not to me :) I have added my controller code to the question and also some more details below it.

Comment: You'll need to make a constructor aswell, where you'll pass the store to your object. And you need to make sure your store is loaded before u call buildContent, it might be better to listen to the load event of the store.

initComponent will have something like: me.store.on('load', function() { me.buildContent() });

Comment: Absolutely! But this could also be done by a controller. Anyway I cleaned up my example.

Comment: Thank @sra. It is working great now, although your update produces an 'attentive is undefined' error. I have one question though - and perhaps more that will require another SO question - how would I filter the data returned by the store? Looking at the documentation, I see there is a filter method but this returns null when run on the store?

Comment: @BrynJ I recommend you to apply `remoteFilter: true` to the store you need to filter. With that you can only filter for params + value. The Filters are packed automatically with each request. At the server you just need to read the list named filter which contains object like { property: 'YurUsedString', value: 'YourUsedValue' }. It is now up to you to apply these filters before returning the request. Local Filters are normally regex or functions . They create a copy of the data while the filter is active. A filter filters the store and has therefor no return value, he just get applied. hth

Comment: @BrynJ Ah yes, and I fixed the `attentive` error. I missed the access modifier